# OS X Terminal ends session at opening : permission denied

Tags: macos, permissions, terminal

I have an issue with Terminal on MacOS X 10.7.4. I know where it comes from, but I don't know how to solve it :

Yesterday, I installed fish-shell as a shell replacement. Following the installation instructions, I ended typing the following command :

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
```

I noticed I had to do a :

```
sudo bash
```

for it to work. 
Once done, I quit.

Today, I try to run Terminal and I see te following message :

```
Last login: Wed Jun 27 12:38:01 on ttys000
login: /usr/local/bin/fish: Permission denied

[Opération terminée]
```

(yes, I'm French, which explains my poor English). I cannot type any command since I have no access to the Terminal.
I tried with iTerm2 but same issue.

No command is set at launch in the default profile of Terminal/iTerm2 (well, in the UI).

How can I take the power back ?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you get stuck without a shell, you can use **Shell > New Command** and enter the name of a different shell, e.g., `bash`, and Terminal will use that shell instead of whatever the shell is set to (make sure that “Run command inside a shell” is not selected). Then you can use that shell to resolve the problem with the other shell, or change the default shell back with `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash` (or whatever shell you prefer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `System Preferences`, open the `Users & Groups` section, right-click on your user and select `Advanced Options`. You can change your `Login shell` setting there.

Answer (score 5):

If you get stuck without a valid shell, you can use **Shell > New Command** and enter the name of a different shell, e.g., `bash`, and Terminal will use that shell instead of the default (make sure that “Run command inside a shell” is not selected).

Then you can use that shell to resolve the problem with the other shell, or change the default shell back with `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash $LOGNAME` (or whatever shell you prefer).

Comment: That actually worked. OSX didn't let me change bash.

Answer (score 1):

First use `Shell > New Command` then use another shell (like C shell `csh`); then use the following command to change the permission:

```
sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/fish
```

Comment: This worked for me. The session was not getting stored prior to this. But once I changed the permissions and restarted iTerm2, new tabs started opening in last open folder. Super!